# PhoneGap Orientation Plugin is not working

Tags: cordova, orientation

I´m trying to get [this](https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation) plugin to work. I don't know whether it works with my cordova version (2.7.0).I´m getting a lot of errors, mostly `"plugin cannot be resolved to a type".`

I need something to control the orientation in phonegap.Is there another way? I want to have a few pages in landscape and the rest in portrait.

Answer (score 1):

I have also have same issue in ios phonegap ....

Just go and update x-code project file (IOS Application target ) change or update support interface orientation and check it all orientation .

it's work